# Exit status of tar confusion

Tags: shell, tar, suse, exitstatus

I am using ksh

dummpy_file does not exist . Finding the exit status of tar

SUSE10 /  tar version GNU 1.15.1

```
>gunzip -d dummpy_file | tar xvf -
gunzip : dummpy_file: No such file or directory
>echo $?
>0
```

SUSE11 /   tar version GNU 1.20

```
>gunzip -d dummpy_file | tar xvf -
gunzip : dummpy_file No such file or directory   
tar : This does not look tar archive  
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors  
>echo $?   
>2
```

Is the difference in behavior due the different tar  versions ? Please help

Comment: What versions of ksh and gunzip do you have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `tar` 1.19 [fixed](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/#releases) the following bug:

```
Recognition of broken archives.
When supplied an archive smaller than 512 bytes in reading mode (-x, -t), previous tar
versions silently ignored it, exiting with code 0. It is fixed. Tar now issues the
following diagnostic message: This does not look like a tar archive, and exits with code 2."
```

When the `gunzip` program at the start of pipeline can't find the file it's supposed to unpack, it exits and emits 0 bytes to its stdout. The old `tar` version behaved as if 0 bytes were a correct tar archive, hence no error message.

Comment: I tried the same test , now instead of non existant file , i used a text file which is around 1MB and rename to abc.tar.gz so that untaring fails . Now also  gunzip -d abc.tar.gz | tar xvf -          gunzip:  abc.tar.gz : is not in gzip format        > echo $?   is giving 0  in the tar version 1.15 . Please tell me if this bug is also fixed in 1.19 ?

Comment: Yes, it's the same thing. The important thing is that the first program doesn't output anything to its standard output (the error message goes to standard error stream, which is separate).